# SSIS SQL Executation Task error: unable to run some sql queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I'm working to make some fact tables (taking some data from some resources, doing some transformations and putting them in a table). My main dilemma is that I can't run any SQL query other than select, update, and insertion. As soon as i try:

```
exec someProcedure
```

or a conditional statement (`if @part1 ...`) or even (`create table ...`) I take errors. Opening the task to build my SQL statements and find problems it gives errors ranging from (The Set SQL construct or statement is not supported.) to (The EXEC SQL construct or statement is not supported.). 
I looked for numerous topics here on stackoverflow but none were actually addressing me problem.

Thanks,

You can see a view of what I'm facing in this picture :

[image]

I expect to run my SQL commands as usual in SSIS.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the SQL Source Type from `Direct Input` to `Stored Procedure` and just specify the stored procedure name instead of `Exec stored procedure`

Also make sure that you have selected the relevant `TargetServerVersion` from the project configuration:

- [How to change TargetServerVersion of my SSIS Project](https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001710233-How-to-change-TargetServerVersion-of-my-SSIS-Project)

---

Based on your comments, you are using SQL Server 2012 with Visual Studio 2010 which are not compatible.

You have to use Visual Studio 2012 or 2015+ (backward compatibility added). You can refer to the SSIS tag wiki for more info:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ssis/info

Comment: Unfortunately I cant find the alternative ( Stored Procedure instead of Direct Input) it seems the only options are file connection and variable

Comment: @AliRa what are the sql server and visual studio versions?

Comment: sql server: 2012, visual studio 2010

Comment: Then you should use visual studio 2012 since vs 2010 is not compatible

Comment: I installed Sql server 2014 and visual studio 2015. no changes occurred...

Comment: @AliRa Have you checked the TargerServerVersion property

Comment: @AliRa check the first link i mentioned

Comment: I checked that and it is already okay and fit with my sql server version, quite annoying that i cannot run my queries ...

Comment: @AliRa what is the connectionstring you are using? Also check that user has needed permissions?

Comment: I mean there isn't any option in accordance to what you said, but could you tell me where to find connectionstring ? in the meantime, I'm already running many of functionalities with ease.

Comment: @AliRa can you provide a screenshot of the ole db connection manager configuration?